# Parse text file with regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to parse some js files (ExtJS) and find all dependencies that are used by class in that file.

Sample js file looks like so:

```
Ext.define('Pandora.controller.Station', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    refs: [{
        ref: 'stationsList',
        selector: 'stationslist'
    }],

    stores: ['Stations', 'RecentSongs'],
    ...
```

What I want to get is `Ext.app.Controller`.

With my code I'm able to get all lines that contains `extend`

```
public void ReadAndFilter(string path)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.Contains("extend"))
            {
                listBox2.Items.Add(line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this also returns comments and other unnecessary things.
My idea was to use RegEx to find all strings.

My problem is that sometimes line has some spaces in front and after extend.
Here are some samples that can be found in js files:

> ```
> extend          : 'Ext.AbstractPlugin',
> extend: 'Ext.util.Observable',
> @extends Sch.feature.AbstractTimeSpan
> extend      : "Sch.feature.AbstractTimeSpan",
> extend              : "Sch.plugin.Lines",
> extend : "Sch.util.DragTracker",
> ```

Running RegEx on this should return:

```
Ext.AbstractPlugin
Ext.util.Observable
Sch.feature.AbstractTimeSpan
Sch.plugin.Lines
Sch.util.DragTracker
```

Here is my attempt: `extend[ ]*:[ ]*['"][a-zA-Z.]*['"]`, I've tested it [here](http://regexr.com?36hsb), but I want only to get part between quotes or double quotes (can this be also validated? So that we can exclude those with first quote and second double quote).

RegEx aren't maybe fastest, but I have no idea how else I could do that.
Any advices are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use a capture group; you wrap the required part between parentheses:

```
extend[ ]*:[ ]*['"]([a-zA-Z.]*)['"]
```

And you access them through `.Groups[1].Value`

---

EDIT: As per request:

```
extend *: *('|")(?<inside>[a-zA-Z.]*)\1
```

With this one, you can access the captured group with `.Groups["inside"].Value`

Comment: Thans for such fast reply. Can I add group name to that regex and ensure it start and ends with quotas or doubleqoutas, like in @Arman's answer?

Comment: Thanks Jerry :) One more thing. Right now I'm scanning file line by line. Can I use the same RegEx to scan entire file at once? This would probably save some time.

Answer (score 4):

```
extend\s*:\s?("|')(.*)\1
```

`\1` is a reference to whatever is captured by the parentheses in `("|')`, so it will force the quotes to match up correctly.

In this case, the matched part (that you want) winds up in `Groups[2].Value`

Also, simply a stylistic suggestion: don't use `[ ]*` for matching spaces, those grouping brackets look too confusing when empty. A simple `\s*` is easier to read and clear to understand.

Comment: was writing this when I saw you'd posted it. Most elegant answer to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are only missing a capture group. Note the parens around `[a-zA-Z.]*`

`extend([ ]*):[ ]*['"]([a-zA-Z.]*)['"]`

To implement this try:

```
var result = from Match match in Regex.Matches(line, "extend([ ]*):[ ]*['"]([a-zA-Z.]*)['"]") 
         select match.ToString();
```