# Find matching words in file using regex

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

This is continuation of my previous question: [Parse text file with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102333/parse-text-file-with-regex), but because I'm creating new expression I don't want to edit that question.

Thanks to Jerry I'm able to find matches but I need to get more complex.

Classes in ExtJS can have requires and mixins section:

```
Ext.define('Ext.Window', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    requires: ['Ext.util.MixedCollection', 'Ext.util.BasicDrag'],
    mixins: {
        draggable: 'Ext.util.Draggable',
        droppable : 'Ext.utils.Droppable'
    }
});
```

Thanks to previous question I'm able to get `extend` part, but from above example I would like to get:

```
Ext.Panel
Ext.util.MixedCollection
Ext.util.BasicDrag
Ext.util.Draggable
Ext.utils.Droppable
```

Can this all be done using single RegEx?  Or maybe 3 different RegEx'es (one from Jerry's answer)

requires section can look as so:

```
requires: 'Ext.util.MixedCollection'
```

or

```
    requires: ['Ext.util.MixedCollection', 'Ext.util.BasicDrag'],
```

or

```
    requires: [
               'Ext.util.MixedCollection', 
               'Ext.util.BasicDrag'
              ],
```

the same with mixins.
Idea behind this is to get all dependencies and build custom minified JS file (I'm aware of Sencha CMD Tool)

I'm able to get single `requires` but I can't get multiple elements to match. My started regex: http://regexr.com?36hto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

`requires\s*:\s*(?:\[)?\s*(?:(?:'([^']+)')(?:,\s*)?)+\s*(?:\],?)?`

http://regexr.com?36huj

EDIT

`requires\s*:\s*(?:\[)?\s*(?:(?:'(?<inside>[a-zA-Z.]*)')(?:,\s*)?)+\s*(?:\],?)?`

That seems to be what you want for named matched

Comment: This looks impressive :) but how can I get matches only? Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19102400/965722. How can I name group to get only needed parts?

Comment: This is my attempt: http://regexr.com?36i1a could You please look at it and check if it is correct?

Comment: The bit in this expression that does the matching is `([^']+)` in the middle. You can replace that with your language specific matching thingy.

Comment: I've added what I think it needs, but this is not my language.

Comment: Thanks :) I'll try to implement this in my app and then well see, but using online testers this looks fine.